# how to get numbers to a specific decimal place c#

Tags: c#

im a newbie doing windows forms c# so i recently wanted to create something like a cashier payment calculation button, but then i got stucked at the rounding part. 
For example, if the total amount is $40.2**3**, how can i make it round up to #40.2**5** instead of going down to $40.2**0**? 
Or maybe $40.2**6** to $40.2**5**?

the total amount values are get from textboxes and the final after-rounded value will be display in textbox as well. 
hope i was not being too unclear about my question. 
thanks guys

Comment: problem is you want to round to same numbers of digits. one better solution is get the last digit of number and identify if its lesser or greater . according to that you replace that last digit. - you will get what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
decimal value = 40.23m;
decimal rounded = Math.Round(value * 20.0m, 0) / 20.0m;
```

Then `rounded` is `40.25m`.

Comment: I fiddled the output for 40.20 to 40.29 : https://dotnetfiddle.net/O5zPB5 seems what OP requires.

Comment: Is there a benefit for using `Math.Round(value * 20.0m, 0)` instead of `Math.Round(value * 2m, 1)`?

Comment: is it possible to use double instead of decimal? sorry for not clearly stating my question before.

Comment: @FeiiMomo: [`Math.​Round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Math_Round_System_Double_System_Int32_) has also an overload for double.

Comment: @FeiiMomo - You're talking about cashier payments so `decimal` should be preferred over `double`.

Comment: @MartinBackasch - It's easier in my mind to round to a whole amount and then convert back down.